# some simple Pointers questions

Tags: c, pointers

Hi please kindly explain to me why is the code generating an error,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char ***x;
    char **q = *x;
    char **(*c) = x;
    char ***d = &q;
    char ***p = "asdasd";

    x=p;

    printf("d:%s\n",d);
    printf("q:%s\n",q);
    printf("x:%s\n",x);


return 0;
```

}

Output:
1
Segmentation fault

Hi Thanks for the replys so if I init x, i still got an Segmentation fault on

```
printf("q:%s\n",q);
```

the output and code is shown below, please kindly advise why is d:1231 instead of 1231123124 and why x=p only change the value of x instead of all (x, q, d)

```
int main(){
    char ***x = "1231123124";
    char **q = *x;
    char **(*c) = x;
    char ***d = &q;
    char ***p = "asdasd";

    x=p;

    printf("p:%s\n",p);
    printf("d:%s\n",d);
//  printf("q:%s\n",q);
    printf("x:%s\n",x);
    printf("c:%s\n",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
 p:asdasd

d:1231

x:asdasd

c:1231123124

Comment: What do you think it should do?

Comment: x undefined and all others followed. P is another undefined.

Comment: You've become a [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Compile with warning level set high, and do not ignore the warnings.

Comment: *>BANG<* *>BANG<* *>BANG<* *>BANG<* *>BANG<* ......

Answer (score 2):

```
char **q = *x;
```

Here you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

It's undefined behaviour, in this case it usually results a segfault (in practice your code will try to dereference some random memory location, or NULL if your compiler initializes local variables (this is typical for debug/non-optimized builds)).

Comment: thanks, but if i add
     char ***x = "12312"; i still got error from  Segmentation fault    printf("q:%s\n",q); line

Comment: @user1998844 Please learn what `char ***x` means before using it.

Answer (score 1):

These are type errors.

```
printf("d:%s\n",d); // d is char***, not char*
printf("q:%s\n",q); // q is char**, not char*
printf("x:%s\n",x); // x is char***, not char*
```

The `%s` specifier expects a `char *` argument, or possibly `void *`, `const char *`, etc., but never a `char **` or `char ***`.